# Open excel file in vb.net with default select option

Tags: vb.net, excel

When I try to open excel files with "Excel found unreadable content in 'filename'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes", I get an error in my vb app. I just want to be able to default to "Yes" and open the file. 
fyi: If I open the excel file and save it and run my code it works fine but I do not want to open every file out of thousands excel files I have and go through this.

Here is my attempt:

```
        Dim r As Excel.Range
        Dim vsn As String
        Try
            oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Open(f, , True)
            oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet
            r = oSheet.Cells(1, 5)
            vsn = r.Value
            VersionControlFile.Write(vsn.Substring(vsn.IndexOf("Version") + 8, 5))
            VersionControlFile.WriteLine()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Exit For
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            'oWB.Close()

        Finally
            oWB.Close()   'I get here when the excel file throws that dialog box.

        End Try
```

Comment: Did you try setting `DisplayAlerts` to `False`?

Comment: Yes I set  oApp.DisplayAlerts = False. Still same error

Comment: Did you try setting the `CorruptLoad` argument of the `Open` method to `xlRepairFile`?

Comment: No but when I set I get an error. Do you set it like this:                 oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Open(f, False, False, , , , , , , , , , , , CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)? I get blue and red underline for xlRepairFile when I do this.

Comment: I think that if you use the commas you don't need the name of the argument.  Try it with just the value.

Comment: I am still getting the same "underline" issue!

Comment: An underline doesn't always mean that it won't work.  The integer value for that is 1.  Maybe it's just the constant name that isn't recognized.

Comment: I set CorruptLoad:=1 or CorruptLoad:=True and it is working great now! Thanks for your help